# Bash access for loops variable via command passed as argument

Tags: bash

I have a frequent situation where I want to run a given command over all files that match a certain pattern. As such I have the following:

**iterate.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
for file in $1; do
    $2
done
```

So I can use it as such `iterate.sh "*.png" "echo $file"`

The problem is when the command is being ran it doesn't seem to have access to the $file variable as that sample command will just output a blank line for every file.

How can I reference the iterator `$file` from the arguments of the program?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash
for file in $1; do
    eval $2
done

iterate.sh "*.png" 'echo $file'
```

Need single quotes around the argument with `$file` so it doesn't expand on the command line. Need to `eval` in the loop to actually do the command in the argument instead of just expanding the argument.

Comment: Ah perfect. I'd tried eval, but not with the single quotes. I'll accept in 7 min.